# How to parse/filter "last" command for displaying logins of a specific date in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: last-command

I want to parse login activity of olny current current date. Last command provides me with multiple rows and columns. How do i filter it or even parse it in Python?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`last` offers the following options for that:

```
-s, --since time
              Display  the  state of logins since the specified time.  This is useful, e.g., to easily determine who was logged in at a particular time.
              The option is often combined with --until.
-t, --until time
              Display the state of logins until the specified time.
-p, --present time
              Display the users who were present at the specified time.  This is like using the options --since and --until together with the same time.
```

About the *time* format, the manpage says:

```
The options that take the time argument understand the following formats:

       YYYYMMDDhhmmss
       YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
       YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm      (seconds will be set to 00)
       YYYY-MM-DD            (time will be set to 00:00:00)
       hh:mm:ss              (date will be set to today)
       hh:mm                 (date will be set to today, seconds to 00)
       now
       yesterday             (time is set to 00:00:00)
       today                 (time is set to 00:00:00)
       tomorrow              (time is set to 00:00:00)
       +5min
       -5days
```

Here some examples:

```
last -s 2017-08-04           # from 2017-08-04 until today
last -s yesterday -t -120min # from yesterday until two hours ago
last -s -4days -t -2days     # from four days ago until two days ago
last -p 2017-08-04           # users present at 2017-08-04 00:00:00
```

Read more about `last` and its options on the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/last.1.html).

Comment: Definitely preferable to use last's own options than launch another utility, +1 from me.

Comment: @Arronical `time last | grep 'Fri Aug[ ]*4'` → 0.007s vs. `time last -s 2017-08-04 -t 2017-08-05` → 0.001s – You can eat 1/512 donut in that spare time. ;) Happy dessert!

Comment: I thought you'd need to add a start and end to avoid how specific it is around times. Shame that -p defaults to 00:00:00 and doesn't use a whole day, but I suppose it shouldn't mess with the known time format.

Comment: I struggled a bit with `-p`: It says it's like `-s` and `-t` together, but the output is totally different. Both have their uses, but they definitely are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output of `last` to `grep`. If you'd like to see all logins from Friday 4th August, use:

```
last | grep 'Fri Aug [ ]*4'
```

Adapt your date string in `grep` accordingly if you wish to view other dates.

Comment: It has to be `last | grep 'Fri Aug[ ]*4'` actually.

Comment: Oh yes, extra spaces. Of course I only tested it using a 2 digit day string!

Comment: By the way, this gives a different output than with the `-s`, `-t` and `-p` options, both being useful in a way.